# Is there any way to bind a differnt click handler to QPushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QPushbutton`:

```py
btn = QPushButton("Click me")
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print("one"))
```

Later in my program, I want to rebind its click handler, I tried to achieve this by calling `connect` again:

```py
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print("two"))
```

I expected to see that the console only prints `two`, but actually it printed both `one` and `two`. In other words, I actually bound two click handlers to the button.

How can I rebind the click handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals and slots in Qt are observer pattern (pub-sub) implementation, many objects can subscribe to same signal and subscribe many times. And they can unsubscribe with `disconnect` function.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    def handler1():
        print("one")

    def handler2():
        print("two")

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("test")
    button.clicked.connect(handler1)
    button.show()

    def change_handler():
        print("change_handler")
        button.clicked.disconnect(handler1)
        button.clicked.connect(handler2)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, change_handler)

    app.exec()
```

In case of lambda you can only disconnect all subscribers at once with `disconnect()` (without arguments), which is fine for button case.